# Filtering data with multiple conditions and selecting from a multi-select in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to render out my data and I want to have a filter so I could filter through them. My filter looks something like this: [image: UI Component of the filter]

So far, I have logic that is being used to filter `completed` and `deleted` item and it is connected to the `<Switch />` (toggle) as shown in the picture. The code is as follows:
**Note that `items` is the original array of items and `filteredItems` is what I mutate everytime I filter.**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (completedSwitch && deletedSwitch) {
      setFilteredItems(
        items
          .filter((el) => el.completed && el.deleted)
      );
    } else if (completedSwitch) {
      setFilteredItems(
        items
          .filter((el) => el.completed)
      );
    } else if (deletedSwitch) {
      setFilteredItems(
        items
          .filter((el) => el.deleted)
      );
    } else {
      setFilteredItems(items);
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [completedSwitch, deletedSwitch]);
```

What I do not understand is how can I integrate the rest of the filters (the multi-select from `username, type, variety, size` to the `useEffect` logic. I know I shouldn't be writing all of the conditions into an `if/else` statement which would be a little crazy. How should I approach this problem? Separate them into 2 `useEffect`? What is your take on this problem?

Additional info:
Currently, I'm storing all of the multi-select values into a state, so I have something like:

```js
const [filteredUser, setFilteredUser] = useState<string>("");
// and so on...

// and an event handler to store the data
const handleUserSelect = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setFilteredUser(e.currentTarget.value);
} 

// the multi-select component
<HTMLSelect onChange={handleUserSelect}>
    <option>User</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    // and so on...
</HTMLSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to handle this in different way. like store selected filters and data in redux or shared state and

using selector you can provide your on custom code which will filter out the data based on your selected filters.

```
export const selectFiltered = (state: IApplicationState): IData[] => {

    let data: IData[] = [...state.data];
    
    data = filterBySearchText(data, state.filter.searchText);    

    return data;
};
```

```
const filterdData = useSelector((state: IApplicationState) => selectFiltered(state));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the filter condition could be expressed like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
      setFilteredItems(
        items.filter((el) => {
            if(completedSwitch !== el.completed) return false;
            else if(deletedSwitch !== el.deleted) return false;
            else if(filteredUser && el.username !== filteredUser) return false;
            // ... the other filter conditions for your multi select values
            else return true;
        }
      )
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [completedSwitch, deletedSwitch, filteredUser, /*...*/]);
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: Just replace the `useEffect` hook you posted above with my example hook